# Returning a list of items based on a partial match

Tags: c#

Say I have the following class:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public Teacher(string teacherName)
    {
        TeacherName = teacherName;
        StudentNames = new List<string>();
    }

    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public List<string> StudentNames { get; set; }
}
```

And say these I have the following code:

```
List<Teacher> teachersList = new List<Teacher>();

Teacher teacherOne = new Teacher("Mrs. Smith");
teacherOne.StudentNames.Add("Johnny");
teacherOne.StudentNames.Add("Samantha");

Teacher teacherTwo = new Teacher("Mr. Andrews");
teacherTwo.StudentNames.Add("Johnny");
teacherTwo.StudentNames.Add("Chris");
teacherTwo.StudentNames.Add("Samantha");

Teacher teacherThree = new Teacher("Ms. Cunningham");
teacherThree.StudentNames.Add("Becky");
teacherThree.StudentNames.Add("Rachel");
teacherThree.StudentNames.Add("Johnny");

Teacher teacherFour = new Teacher("Mr. Pearson");
teacherFour.StudentNames.Add("Samantha");
teacherFour.StudentNames.Add("Rachel");
teacherFour.StudentNames.Add("Kevin");

teachersList.Add(teacherOne);
teachersList.Add(teacherTwo);
teachersList.Add(teacherThree);
teachersList.Add(teacherFour);
```

I want to pull the Teachers that have both Johnny and Samantha in their list of StudentNames. This means only teacherOne and teacherTwo should return, and not teacherThree and teacherFour because they only have one or the other. I've tried the following, but it pulls back all four teachers because of the way it's doing a partial match:

```
List<string> matchingStudents = new List<string>();
matchingStudents.Add("Johnny");
matchingStudents.Add("Samantha");
return teachersList.Where(teacher => teacher.StudentNames.Any(studentName => matchingStudents.Any(studentName2 => studentName2.Equals(studentName)))).ToList();
```

I feel like I'm missing something, maybe I'd have to do something with an intersection or union. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
return teachersList
    .Where(teacher => matchingStudents.All(teacher.StudentNames.Contains))
    .ToList();
```

If you want to ignore the case it's little bit more code:

```
return teachersList
    .Where(t => matchingStudents.All(s => t.StudentNames.Contains(s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: All() was definitely what I lacked. Thank you!

Comment: @LOL.NO.: Not only the `All`, it's kind of a perspective issue. We sometimes need to think from the other direction. You don't want teachers where their students have any name. You focus on the name-list that you search, [**all**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0) names must be found in the teacher's student-list. If you notice that you will find out which method to use.

Comment: @LOL.NO. Making `matchingStudents` into a `HashSet` instead of a `List` can be more performant, it also sorts out the case-insensitive problem as you can pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to it's constructor.

Comment: Ah yes `teacher.StudentNames` instead, sorry wasn't thinking